# What error could be called in the file system Node.js module?

Tags: node.js, fs, writefile

I am simply wondering what error could be called in the writeFile() method from the fs module in Node.js. Here is an example:

```
const fs = require("fs");

fs.writeFile("hello-world.txt", "Hello World!", (error) => {
     if (error) {
          // handle error
     }
     console.log("Task completed!");
});
```

This method, in this example, writes "Hello World!" to the "hello-world.txt" file, but if that file does not exist, the file will be created with the contents "Hello World!" in it. In the callback function, an 'error' argument is passed in. What possible error could be thrown whilst this method is executed? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are quite a few that might occur!

Like the directory does not exist, e.g.

```
const fs = require("fs");

fs.writeFile("/path/doesnt/exist/hello-world.txt", "Hello World!", (error) => {
    if (error) {
        console.error("An error occurred:", error);
    } else {
        console.log("Task completed!");
    }
});
```

Or you include an illegal char in the file name:

```
const fs = require("fs");

fs.writeFile("hello?world.txt", "Hello World!", (error) => {
    if (error) {
        console.error("An error occurred:", error);
    } else {
        console.log("Task completed!");
    }
});
```

Or

- You don't have access to the file
- The file is read only
- Out of disk space

And there are probably some more, in most cases they'll be unlikely to happen, but of course in programming something that is unlikely to happen always does :-)